# How to collect only container logs with Datadog without host and container metrics?

Tags: logging, datadog

I not found answer on official website and support can't give an answer. So I ask the community.

I want use Log Management without using Datadog Infrastructure.

There is a link on the official site, but it is no longer available and a redirect to another page is no answer to the question. https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/faq/can-the-datadog-agent-be-used-to-send-only-logs/

Also, I couldn't find a copy of this page on the Internet.

My agent config:

```yml
agent:
    image: datadog/agent:7.25.0
    environment:
      - DD_API_KEY={{ datadog_api_key }}
      - DD_SITE=datadoghq.eu
      - DD_PROCESS_AGENT_ENABLED=false
      - DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true
      - DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /proc/:/host/proc/:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /opt/datadog-agent/run:/opt/datadog-agent/run:rw
```

THis collect container logs without container metrics. But collect host metrics.

How to disable collect host metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, new documentation link:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/how-to-set-up-only-logs

```sh
docker run -d --name datadog-agent \
           -e DD_API_KEY="<DATADOG_API_KEY>" \
           -e DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true \
           -e DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true \
           -e DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE="name:datadog-agent" \
           -e DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_EVENTS=false
           -e DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERIES=false
           -e DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERVICE_CHECKS=false
           -e DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SKETCHES=false
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
           -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
           -v /opt/datadog-agent/run:/opt/datadog-agent/run:rw \
           -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
           gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:latest
```